# Hadoop not working because "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.ConfTest."

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop 3.0 on a newly reformatted Linux SUSE server.  Normally I would think I did it correctly.  But no hadoop commands are working.

For example I try to run `hadoop conftest` and I get an error `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.ConfTest`.

I modified the hadoop file.  I included this stanza near the top of the bin/hadoop file:

```
set -xv
```

I then ran `hadoop conftest` and here are the last 30 lines of output:

```
++ HADOOP_OPTS='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=ec2-user -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender'
+ [[ - = \  ]]
+ hadoop_debug 'HADOOP_OPTS accepted -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ hadoop_translate_cygwin_path HADOOP_HOME
+ [[ false = \t\r\u\e ]]
+ hadoop_translate_cygwin_path HADOOP_CONF_DIR
+ [[ false = \t\r\u\e ]]
+ hadoop_translate_cygwin_path HADOOP_COMMON_HOME
+ [[ false = \t\r\u\e ]]
+ hadoop_translate_cygwin_path HADOOP_HDFS_HOME
+ [[ false = \t\r\u\e ]]
+ hadoop_translate_cygwin_path HADOOP_YARN_HOME
+ [[ false = \t\r\u\e ]]
+ hadoop_translate_cygwin_path HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME
+ [[ false = \t\r\u\e ]]
+ [[ false = true ]]
+ hadoop_java_exec conftest org.apache.hadoop.util.ConfTest
+ local command=conftest
+ local class=org.apache.hadoop.util.ConfTest
+ shift 2
+ hadoop_debug 'Final CLASSPATH: /usr/local/hadoop/conf'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ hadoop_debug 'Final HADOOP_OPTS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=ec2-user -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ hadoop_debug 'Final JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib64/jvm/jre'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ hadoop_debug 'java: /usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin/java'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ hadoop_debug 'Class name: org.apache.hadoop.util.ConfTest'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ hadoop_debug 'Command line options: '
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ export CLASSPATH
+ exec /usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin/java -Dproc_conftest -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=ec2-user -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.ConfTest
```

What is wrong with my installation?

Edit:

I ran this command:

```
hdfs classpath
```

I saw this as the result:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
```

Comment: That classpath variable seems to be pointing at a conf folder, not a Java class location

Comment: I searched for how to change it, but I found alternatives to changing it.  The `hdfs classpath` command does not show a "conf" in it.